# PayPal we are unable to validate your information. Please try again Sandbox

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn

Everything has been working until now. I'm having a issue this morning with PayPal sandbox giving me a error message - We are unable to validate your information. Please try again.

I have a working shopping cart that works with real payments but not sandbox payments. I'm not sure if PayPal are aware of this or I might of changed an account setting or something. I'm just wondering if someone knows why I'm getting this error.

[image]

CLICK HERE TO VIEW SITE - http://goo.gl/lqaJm6

I have cleared cookies, tried different browsers and different devices.

If you need any more information such as code please let me know. Any help is appreciated :D

Form Action

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
            <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
```

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**

This might be the issue:

Sandbox Status Update

Update: We continue to work towards a resolution and will provide an update when we have more information.

Sent Sep 15, 2013 11:24 AM BST by SAR

Start time: Sep 15, 2013 05:55 AM BST

At this time, there is no alternative work-around.

Comment: i think you need more info in your form :-/ https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/buynow_buttons/#id08A2G0AF0BI

Comment: @Bob thank you, It seems to be working now!? I recon it was PayPal, and thanks for that link, it looks very useful. I am going to have a read through it :D

Answer (score 0):

It was a PayPal issue:

**Resolved:** This issue has been resolved as of Sep 15, 2013 11:52 AM BST. 
Sent Sep 15, 2013 12:14 PM BST by SAR

A history of updates can be found at the end of this notification or at our Sandbox blog post.
Start time: Sep 15, 2013 05:55 AM BST

https://www.paypal-notify.com/eventnotification/event_details?eventId=3945